# Backbone view get model variable after model has finished fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone.js, how can i retrieve a veriable that is returned by a model function after the fetch has completed? As I understand the model cannot communicate with the view, so how can the view listen in on the model specific function fetch?

Thanks!

My attempt to do this can be seen below (if you see code mistakes, don't mind them, I wrote this as an example of what I'm trying to do):

```
var ScheduleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/schedule/1',
        getSubjectData: function(){
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data, scheduleData){
                    return scheduleData;
                }
            });
        }
});

var ScheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
         console.log(this.model.getSubjectData());
    }
});
```

Comment: are you still having problems triggering a function after fetch complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to several model events with `listenTo`:

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

since `model.fetch` triggers the 'change' event (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) somewhat similar in your view code:

```
var ScheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.model.getSubjectData());
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.doSmthng);
    },
    doSmthng: function () {
        // ....
    }
});
```

should fire the `doSmthng` models' fetch is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `fetch` inside view like this.

```
var ScheduleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.fetch({success: function() {
             //you can do your stuff here. 
             //Try to get model data using `model.get`.
        }});    
    }
}
```

and,

```
As I understand the model cannot communicate with the view.
```

This is wrong. You can set like this inside your `view`.

```
this.model.view = this;
```

and you can access view in your model as like this.

```
this.view
```

But in my apps i am not doing this. Accessing view inside model will collapse the purpose of backbone.